JsonPropertyAttribute PropertyName ignored by MongoDB
I have a data model in a ASP.NET Core application running .NET 8, where the property names is defined with JsonProperty(PropertyName = "xxx") attributes, like this:
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "enable_cancel_login")]
public bool EnableCancelLogin { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "enable_create_user")]
public bool EnableCreateUser { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "claim_transforms")]
public List<OAuthClaimTransform> ClaimTransforms { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
public string Title { get; set; }

I know it is possible to define the element names with the MongoDB [BsonElement("xxx")] attribute, but I do not want to decorate all the properties in the model with one more attribute.
How can I get MongoDB to use the JsonPropertyAttribute?

You can implement the JsonProperty read functionality in a MongoDB Convention:
public class MongoDbJsonPropertyConvention : ConventionBase, IMemberMapConvention
{
    public void Apply(BsonMemberMap memberMap)
    {
        memberMap.SetElementName(GetElementName(memberMap) ?? memberMap.MemberName);
    }

    private string GetElementName(BsonMemberMap memberMap)
    {
        if (memberMap.MemberName != "Id")
        {
            var jsonPropertyAtt = memberMap.MemberInfo.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonPropertyAtt?.PropertyName))
            {
                return jsonPropertyAtt.PropertyName;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

You should probably ignore the Id properties.
Then, when creating the mongo client, you need to register the MongoDbJsonPropertyConvention in the ConventionRegistry :
var pack = new ConventionPack
{
  new IgnoreIfNullConvention(true),
  new MongoDbJsonPropertyConvention()
};
ConventionRegistry.Register("Read JsonProperty Attribute", pack, t => true);

The t => true is to make it global.
